# JLabel break long words

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a `JLabel` in a `JFrame` like this:

```
public class LabelTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit");

        Dimension size = new Dimension(200, 200);

        label.setMaximumSize(size);
        frame.setSize(size);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The label is displayed, but there are no line wraps, so the text gets cut off:

[image]

---

To fix this issue, I wrapped the text in a <html>-tag. This seems to do the job for simple strings:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit</html>");
```

[image]

---

So far, so good. But there is a problem when a single word exceeds the line length, which causes a text overflow again:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>Loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicielit</html>");
```

[image]

---

How can I tell the JLabel to break the text even if it has to split a word to force a line break? I already tried surrounding the text with `<body style="word-wrap: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word;">` without success.

Comment: *"I already tried surrounding the text with `<body style="word-wrap: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word;">` without success."* The Swing HTML rendering engine is ***very*** basic. It only supports (most of) HTML 3.2 & has *very limited* support for styling. How about a text area (`JTextArea`) configured to *look* like label?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I try to find a way to do it using a `JLabel` in my actual program as it simplifies many other things.

Comment: *"it simplifies many other things"* It'd take about 10-15(?) lines of code to make a text area look & behave (mostly) like a label. What are some of the things that are simplified by sticking with a label? (Noting that the label is also making this 'wrap on width' ability anything *but* simple.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson For example, I have to use HTML tags like `<strong>` inside my label, which doesn't work for a JTextArea.

Comment: There is no component in Swing which is satisfied all of your requirements. So either you reduce your requirements or you need to write your own component.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy What about a `JTextPane`? (Yes, meant as a question, I have not dealt with them enough to know if they can provide all the OP requires - styling, text wrap on character width..) OP: is a mono spaced font allowable?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I know my requirements are high, but I would like for the solution to look like a normal JLabel.

Comment: *"I would like for the solution to look like a normal JLabel."* Yes I got that before my first comment. Please answer my latest question re the mono spaced font. (A `JLabel` **can** have a mono spaced font!)

Comment: @AndrewThompson No, I do not want to use a monospaced font.

Comment: Got it. Well.. that's me out of ideas.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm not sure, but I think that `JTextPane` has the same rendering engine as the `JLabel`.

Comment: Swing HTML rendering does support `<pre>`. Can you dynamically format the text before applying it to the `JLable` ?